# jsf project is showing blank in web browser

Tags: jsf

I am using eclipse to create a jsf project using jboss server...when i run the server i dont get any inptfields or buttons ,,page is showing blank
please help me how to solve this error..can anyone suggest me any ideas.......why all the tags are not working

[image]
THIS IS THE RESULT I GET.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
       xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        >
    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World - Input Forms</title>
        <style>
        .error{
        color:red;
         list-style: none;
       
        }
         .error ul {
   
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
        .box{
        margin-left:400px;
        padding:5px;
        margin-top:100px;
        background-color:lightgray;
        color:black;
        text-align: center;
        width:500px;
         border-radius:7px;
        }
        .input{
        border-radius:3px;
        height:18px;
        }
        .radio{
        margin-left:170px}
        .submit{
        margin-bottom:15px}
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form styleClass="box">
    <b>STUDENT DETAILSS</b> 
    
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        

<div>
 <h:inputText styleClass="input" value="#{student.firstName}" label="firstname"
                            a:placeholder="First name" required="true" id="first" />
                            </div>
                            <div> <h:message for="first"  styleClass="error" /></div>
<br></br>

        <div>
<h:inputText styleClass="input" value="#{student.lastName}" label="lastname"
                            a:placeholder="Last name" required="true" id="last"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <h:message for="last"  styleClass="error" />
                            </div>
                        
            <br></br>
            <div>
<h:inputText styleClass="input"  label="age"   value="#{student.age}"
                            a:placeholder="Age" required="true" >
                            <f:validateLongRange minimum="5" maximum="17"/>
                        
        </h:inputText>   
            </div>              
                    <br></br>
        <h:inputText styleClass="input"  label="Roll Number" value="#{student.rollnumber}" a:placeholder="Roll Number" required="true" />
                            <br></br>
                                <br></br>
            <h:inputText styleClass="input"  label="class" value="#{student.section}" a:placeholder="class" required="true" />
                            <br></br>
        <br></br>
         <div>
         <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Select your section         " />
        
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{student.selectedOption}">
<f:selectItem itemValue ="A" itemLabel="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="B" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C " itemLabel="C" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
<div></div>
<br></br>
    
        <div>
         phone: <h:inputText label="phone"  id="ph" value="#{student.phone}"
                                    required="true" validatorMessage="format:xxx-xxx-xxxx">
                                    <f:validateRegex pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"/>
                         </h:inputText>
                         </div>
                         <div>
             <h:message for="ph"  styleClass="error" />
             </div>
        <br></br>
<h:selectManyCheckbox styleClass="radio" value="#{student.gender}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="male" itemLabel="Male" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="female" itemLabel="Female" />
   
  </h:selectManyCheckbox>
  <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <h:commandButton styleClass="submit" value="Submit" action="response" />
            <br></br>
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

is there something wrong with the code or what....server is working fine

Comment: not this does not help